# Which transformations can be performed on data that maintain the i.i.d. property of a sample?

Tags: data-transformation, iid

I have problems to understand how data transformations interact with the  property of samples being i.i.d. Especially when nontrivial operations are performed on each element of the sample, I am not sure how one can detect or show whether an operation maintains the property of i.i.d.

For instance, if we have a distribution $f$ and draw an independent sample $X$ from $f$. If we apply the same rigid transformation $t(x) = ax + c$ on each element $ x \in X$ the resulting set is also an i.i.d. sample (of a different distribution $f'$), correct? Based on $f$ and $t(x)$, one should even be able to formulate the distribution $f'$.

In contrast, if the transformation searches for the closest other point in $X$ and returns their difference, i.e., $t'(x) = \min_{x' \in X \setminus \{x\}} |x - x'|$, I am not sure if $\{t'(x) | x \in X\}$ is an i.i.d. sample of any distribution. On the one hand the transformation depends on the sample $X$, which sounds like it could produce dependent observations.
On the other hand, these distances seem to mostly depend on the densities of $f$ and may be formulated using expected values.

I know there is no test, whether a sample is i.i.d., but I am curious whether there are criterions to determine if a transformation maintains or removes this property?

Comment: There is no universal answer.  To see why it must be contingent, consider an iid sample of size two.  Call the random variables $X$ and $Y$.  The transformation $X^\prime = X+Y, Y^\prime=X-Y$ generally produces *dependent* samples from what can be strikingly different distributions.  (For instance, if the distribution is supported on positive numbers, $X+Y$ will be positive but $X-Y$ could be anything.)  However, if you assume the underlying distribution is *Normal*, then $X^\prime$ and $Y^\prime$ are iid!

Comment: A critical difference between your first example transformation and your second is that the second transformation depends on more than just the current data point (the one you're transforming), while the first did not.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, I am aware of that and put it there purposely. What I am unsure about is, what the consequence of this dependence is. As whuber has shown (very much appreciated), it is not a direct consequence that the resulting data points are dependent. So, if the transformation depends on more than one value, is it at least a good rule of thumb that the result would not be i.i.d.? If someone claims otherwise in a specific case (i.e. given the original distribution and transformation), are there methods to prove or disprove that claim?

Comment: The point I was getting at was there's a large class of transformations for which you do have independence (much larger than the linear class you mention)